# C#: How to format a string using string.Format without knowing the size of an array?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have an array in a loop.

At a time, the array could have a different size(could be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` etc elements)

How could I use the `string.Format` without specifying the exact size of the array:

Code in case of a list with 6 members.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                              line = stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0, -40} 
                              {1, -40} {2, -25} {3, -15} {4, -15} {5, -15} ",
                              listString[0], listString[1], listString[2],
                              listString[3], listString[4], listString[5]))
                              .ToString();

Console.WriteLine(line)
```

I need a piece of code which formats my string without writing a specific code in case of a specific number of elements. Any feature I don't know? :)

Comment: The formats you hae shown are not the same for all elements.... So... What are the rules?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is not your problem here, based on your description I think your question is about `String.Format`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right. :) Sorry for the mistake. :)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, don't use `string.Format` here - instead, just loop over the array, using Append for each element, using an appropriate format specifier.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++) {
    if(i!=0) builder.Append(' ');
    // need to apply format per i, it seems        builder.Append(arr[i].ToString(formatSpecifier));
}
builder.AppendLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, I thought I would answer for anyone else who came here from google.

My approach would be to use a foreach loop and  a StringBuilder, then append each element to the end of the string.
Once the string is 'built' just print the string in your String.Format

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(int number in listString)
{
    sb.Append(number).Append("\n");    //or whatever separator you would like
}
string sbResult = sb.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Write your content here {0}", sbResult));
```

Hope this is still helpful to someone.